# Prevent easy downloading of mp3s that play on mp3 players?

Tags: wordpress, mp3

I have mp3 players set up on my site to play mp3s. At the moment, users can easily look through the source, run a search for "mp3" and download all of the music on my site. I know it's virtually impossible to completely prevent a determined user from downloading the music but I want to make it harder for the average user. Is there any way I can obfuscate the links to the mp3s?

Relevant site: http://boyceavenue.com/music

Comment: keep them outside your document root and serve them up via a script, e.g. `getmp3.php?id=XXX`. as long as XXX isn't an incrementing integer, they'd have to work harder to get a list of "valid" id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the language you are using. To expand upon what Marc B wrote, I would recommend using the PHP [`http_send_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-send-file.php) command along with the checksum of the file.

To send the file, use the following:

```
$filename = "/absolute/or/relative/path/to/file.ext";
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg"; // See note below
http_send_content_disposition($filename, true);
http_send_content_type($mime_type);
http_throttle(0.1, 2048);
http_send_file($filename);
```

If you are serving up multiple types of files using PHP 5.3.0 or later, you could determine the mimetype this way:

```
$filename = "/absolute/or/relative/path/to/file.ext";
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Calculating the checksum is simple enough. Just use [`md5_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php).

So, what can you do with the checksum?

Well, you could create an array of checksums and filenames that cross-reference each other. That is, you include the checksum in the links to the file, but have a little routine that looks up the checksum and delivers the mp3 file. You also could do this in a database. You also could do like some apps that store files in a directory structure based on their checksums (`music/3/3a/song.mp3` with a checksum of 3a62f6 or whatever).

If you don't care about the filenames being mangled, you could save the files with a checksum for the filename. That could be done at upload time (if your files are being uploaded) or through a batch script (using the CLI).

Another thing you should do is to put a default document (index.php or whatever) that tells people to look elsewhere. Also disable browsing the directory. If only a very small number of people will need access, you could also throw a password on the directory, thus requiring a login to access the files.